# Deal price at google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data of orders where there can be multiple products per one order. I struggle to automatically compute the total order price. Didn't find any formula for it.
There is what I mean:
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GbXL.png)

In the last column I want to see the sum of product prices with the same order number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Sumif:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,sumif(A2:A,A2:A,C2:C)))
```

[image]

Note:

At time of writing Sumifs can't be used this way so you can't add an additional condition to the formula.

Comment: This works! Great-great thank you!
Just in my sheets "," replaces with ";"

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting multiple duplicate values in Total Price column (`D`).
[image]

My suggestion is to add another sheet to display Total Price by order number.

If you add Sheet2 and put the following formulas inside:

1. in cell `A1` put this formula
   `={"Order Number";UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)}`
   to look in Sheet1 and get only unique order numbers.
2. in cell B1 put this formula
   `={"Total Price";ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A="","",SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A, A2:A,Sheet1!C2:C)))}`
   to calculate for each unique Order Number the total sum of all product prices.

You will get this clean table showing you the total price for each order number:
[image]

Comment: You are looking ahead of time:)
That's what I'm going to do with the income of the day!
Thank you for advance help. It worked. I really appreciate it!